# tilt.js pushes parallax element down a few pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parallax

I am working on a web design. In the web design, I have an image. I added parallax effect to the image with the help of `rellax.js`. This is the code for adding parallax effect to the image with `rellax.js`

Now I want to use `tilt.js` to add the tilt effect to the image. When I hover over the image now, the image is pushed down a few pixels. I don't face this problem when I remove the parallax effect.

The tilt effect itself works, but I don't want the image to be pushed down.

```js
var rellax = new Rellax('.rellax');
```

```css
.about_img {
  height: 600px;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
  border: 5px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 150px 150px 50px 0px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 10px 10px 10px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 10px 10px 10px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tilt.js@1.1.21/dest/tilt.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rellax/1.10.0/rellax.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rellax/1.10.0/rellax.min.js"></script>
<img src='images/about.jpg' alt="" class='about_img rellax' data-rellax-speed="2" data-tilt>
```

One possible solution for the problem is by adding a negative margin-top value on hover like this

```
img:hover{
  margin-top: -100px;
}
```

This solution is not very elegant and the outcome is very glitchy.

Why does this problem occur, and what can be done to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, I fixed this by using a parent and a child div, where the parent div has the Rellax effect and the child has the Tilt effect, I know this is a work-around and somebody might have a better solution.

Here's an example of the idea I've implemented.

https://codepen.io/ndrs/pen/ExgQBqz

```
<div class="half rellax" data-rellax-speed="1"> <!-- has rellax -->
  <div class="inner-project"> <!-- has tilt -->
    <h3>Two</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ps. I see you're importing Rellax.js twice in your code example. Just use either one depending on your needs.